# Why does scanf skip getting string input?

Tags: c, char, scanf, getchar

I am trying to get multiple words input and multiple lines into one array. But somewhere the code skips getting the input and skips to end the program. I have tried adding space before and after the ' %s' (or '%s ') but it won't work (maybe because it's inside a loop?). Would really appreciate anyone's help! It also starts to act weird if I enter more than two-three words :(
My goal is to find how many times a specific letter has occurred throughout all those words and lines.

```
#include <stdio.h> //include standard library

int main(){
  int lineCount, occuranceCount;
  printf("How many lines are you going to enter?");
  scanf("%d", &lineCount);

  char input[lineCount][100], searchChar;

  for(int i=0; i<lineCount; i++){
    printf("Please enter line #%d (100 characters of less):",i+1);
    scanf("%s", &input[i]);
  }

  printf("What letter do you want to check the frequence in those lines? ");
  scanf("%c", &searchChar);

  for(int j=0; j<lineCount; j++){
    for(int k=0; k<100; k++){
      if(input[j][k] != '\0'){
        if(input[j][k]==searchChar)
          occuranceCount++;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("The letter occurs for %d time", occuranceCount);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which is one of the primary reasons why `fgets` (or POSIX `getline`) are recommended for user input instead of `scanf` which is full of pitfalls for the unwary... Regardless which input function you use, you must ***validate the return*** to have any confidence you will not invoke *Undefined Behavior* on your next attempt to access what you attempted to read.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &input[i]);` -> `scanf("%99s", input[i]);`

Comment: A summary of why it skps? (1) you read with `scanf ("%d"...)` which leaves the `'\n'` (from the user pressing *Enter* in `stdin`. (2) you call `scanf ("%s"...)` which reads nothing because the `"%s"` *format specifier* reads from the beginning up to the first *whitepace* (`'\n'` being whitespace) which is not removed from `stdin`; (3) you call `scanf ("%c"...)` which happily accepts the `'\n'` as a *character* for its input and (4) you fail to check the return of all of the calls.

Comment: "Questions seeking **debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")** must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]!"

Comment: Your question is lacking the exact *input/output* that you're feeding into the program and receiving from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  scanf(" %c", &searchChar);
         ^
```

You need the space over here to consume any `\n` from `stdin`.

Also `scanf()` will read one word not a line(space separated words) as you are thinking.

And also it is better to use `strlen(input[j])` to know how much you should read.

Another thing, use `size_t` instead of `int` in the looping.

Intialize `occuranceCount` to `0`.

Also to avoid `buffer overrun` exploits use `scanf("%99s", input[i]);` in your code.

In order to read a line you can use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 4):

1) Change

```
  scanf("%c", &searchChar); -->   scanf(" %c", &searchChar);
```

to get rid of any `\n` left in the input buffer from previous `scanf`

2) Change

```
for(int k=0; k<100; k++){ --> for(int k=0; k<strlen(input[j]); k++){
```

to avoid reading beyond the actual user input.

Besides that:

Never do `scanf("%s", &input[i]);` as the user can overflow your input buffer. At least change it to: `scanf("%99s", &input[i]);` but consider using `fgets` instead

Using `fgets` your program could be:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(){
  size_t lineCount = 0, occuranceCount = 0;
  printf("How many lines are you going to enter?");
  scanf("%zu ", &lineCount);
  if (lineCount == 0) return 0;  // Input error

  char input[lineCount][100], searchChar;

  for(size_t i=0; i<lineCount; i++){
    printf("Please enter line #%zu (100 characters of less):",i+1);
    fgets(input[i], 100, stdin);
  }

  printf("What letter do you want to check the frequence in those lines? ");
  scanf("%c", &searchChar);

  for(size_t j=0; j<lineCount; j++){
    for(size_t k=0; k<strlen(input[j]); k++){
        if(input[j][k]==searchChar) occuranceCount++;
    }
  }

  printf("The letter occurs for %zu time", occuranceCount);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%zu ", &lineCount);` does not return until a line of non-white-space text is entered _after_ the line count.  Mixing `scanf()` with `fgets()` is challenging.  Better to only use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 2):

scanf using the %s always read until a ' '(whitespace) or '\n'(new line) is encountered, so you always can read only one word with scanf("%s", s1)...

if you want to read the spaces or new line characters you must use gets, or fgets(more secure than gets)